# Como hacer que un link se quede de un color mientras se visita

Tags: javascript, html, css

bunas, Estoy practicando código haciendo páginas (simplemente de pruebas) y 
practicando me encontré con un problema, y es que.... cuando hago click en la página que quiero ingresar (ya sea index u otra) no soy capaz de hacer que quede marcada la página que estoy visitando EJEMPLO: index(azul)
                                               página2(rojo)
                                               página3(rojo)

mi index (al igual que las otras páginas) tiene una imagen acompañada del texto ej:  (imagen)Index.
     (imagen)página2.
     (imagen)página3.

cada Link tiene un `onmouseover` para que la imagen cambie (simulando una animación). Quiero que al hacer click en "Index" (o las otras páginas) me cambie la imagen a otra sin `onmouseover` (o sea, imagen estática) que identifique que estoy en esa página. Todo el código que implique eso lo quiero poner en un ".inc" y agregar ese ".inc" en mis páginas con "include". Solo sé usar html, css y muy poco de php y js, así que agradecería soluciones con esos lenguajes. Dese ya muchas gracias, valoro mucho su tiempo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: talvez estas usando jquery?? como realizas la navegación???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si te va a gustar la idea , pero creo que lo que haría es:

Cuando se cargue la pagina, `$(document).ready()`.

Mirar la dirección,`var URL = window.location;`.

En función de la dirección cambiar el css del elemento que me interesa.
`if(URL==index)
$("#index").css("background-color", "blue");`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var URL = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(URL);
  if(URL = '/questions/290395/como-hacer-que-un-link-se-quede-de-un-color-mientras-se-visita'){
    $('#index').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a id = 'index' href="./inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a id = 'contacto' href="./contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
   <li><a id = 'nos' href="./nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Combinaría mi solución con la de Hussein, es decir, en el document ready , en vez de cambiar el css, añadiría la clase active al elemento que me interesa.

Comment: "No sé si te va a gustar la idea". 
Jajajaja, pues sí que me gustó. No es la más práctica tu respuesta pero sí que me ayudó bastante, sin ti no podría haberle encontrado la vuelta para conseguir lo que quería. Gracias por su tiempo buen hombre xD jajaja, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que añadir una clase CSS al elemento que quieras colorear, dependiendo de la pagina en la que estés:

Ej. Tienes 3 paginas: inicio.html - contacto.html - nosotros.html

Y el menu lo tienes tal que así

```html
<ul>
   <li><a href="./inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="./contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
   <li><a href="./nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
</ul>
```

Pues si estás en la página de inicio tendrias que añadir una clase de CSS que coloree el texto como tu quieras

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><a href="./inicio.html" class="active">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="./contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
   <li><a href="./nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
</ul>
```

Para hacerlo de forma automática por PHP está respuesta te puede servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336200/add-class-active-to-active-page-using-php

Comment: Hacerlo de forma automática es lo que estaba buscando, el link que pusiste al final, me ayudó bastante, gracias por tu respuesta, saludos.